# How do I perform a search in Rails3?

Tags: sql, search, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

I'm aware that I can search queries by calling `where()` on a model as follows:
`Post.where(:title => 'My First Post')`

However, what if I don't know if the user wants to filter out the search parameters?
For example, I have a search form that has an optional `title` field. If the title is filled, the form should search for a title. If it is not, however, the form should just return all fields.

I tried doing something along the lines of

```
search = Post.all
if params[:title].present?
   search.where(:title => params[:title])
end
```

However, Rails immidiately returns the result of the search when I call Post.all and I cannot further add conditions/

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.all` is a 'finisher' method for arel and causes the query to actually be called (same goes for `.each` and `.first`). So, if you want to be able to keep building up the scope conditionally, `.all` should be the last thing called, if you want to call it at all.

Comment: Then how would I get the resource without retrieving the fields so I can continue calling conditions on it? Thanks!

Comment: One option is to set `search = Post.unscoped` or `search = Post.scoped` which will leave you with an arel relation to play with. Alternatively, rethink the way you're conditionally adding scopes and try to deal with it more gracefully in the model.

Answer (score 1):

Given that there really isn't much in the way of relations to chain here, it would seem that a simple one-liner with a ternary operator might do:

```
@posts = params[:title].present? ? Post.where(:title => params[:title]) : Post.all
```

... because when there is no :where clause scope, you couldn't later chain it to :all, anyway.

Comment: Right, but this was just an example. Imagine I possibly have to call 5 different conditions here depending on user input. How would I get a resource without calling `.all` so I can continue calling conditions on it? Thanks!

Comment: Okay. So you could maybe start with post_query = Post.scoped, and then build on top of this base scope, e.g. post_query = post_query.where(:title => params[:title]) etc.